# How to initialize an ordered pair of (int,string) in java

Tags: java, arrays

Just want to ask how to initialize an ordered pair having the value of (int,string) in java.

example of these pairs are:

(1 , Michael)
(2, Joseph)
(3, Albert)
(4, Maria)

**
Added question, what if the names or the string came from an array??

Comment: You need to give more information.  What's the sorting supposed to be like?  And what do you mean, "come from an array"?  Can you post some code to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: your question is not clear for us, so be specific, what you want ??

Comment: sorry, I asked a general question. I just want to know how to initialize an ordered pair of an integer and string. The string in the ordered pair should came from an arraylist called "Name".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a custom class having integer and string fields:

```
class Pair
{
  int num;
  String name;

  Pair(int num, String name)
  {
     this.num = num;
     this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Then, you can have an array of these `Pair` objects:

```
Pair[] pairs = new Pair[10];
```

And initializing could be like:

```
String[] strings; // your string array.

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   Pair[i] = new Pair(i, strings[i]);
```

Comment: Why the need for the index variable at all? It looks like `index` follows `i`, so effectively, you could just have `Pair[i] = new Pair(i, strings[i]);`

Comment: @TimoteeTheCodeMonkee sorry, i was in hurry to answer, and didn't notice that =) can you delete your comment now?